# Sending an argument to the node.js server side code

Tags: node.js, faye

I am using node.js with Faye for implementing a comet solution. Right now,i have the code for node.js server file to publish data on a channel. But, I have a need where i need to send the channel name to the node.js server side code as an argument and the server then publishes data on that particular channel.

How can i do this ? Any ideas will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This is not really question to your answer, but http://socket.io is more actively developed (right now) and has rooms concept => http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/5/roomsn.png/

Comment: I have worked a bit with 0.7.7 version of socket.io...does it have the room concept in 0.7.7 version? Btw, you wrote "question for my answer". Its "answer for my question" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out how to do it. You have to send a HTTP request like this and send it to the Faye server

{"channel":"/the/channel","data":{"the":"message"}}

This will publish the message in /the/channel

Thanks to Alfred for his response as well

Comment: Your welcome. Maybe you should accept this answer instead.. Because I think this is really the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not precisly the answer to your question, but I would still advice you to check out [socket.io](http://socket.io). Socket.io is more actively developed (right now) and also has a rooms(version 0.7.x) concept. See image below for example.

[image: rooms]